# callback is not a function in a mongodb query using node js´s async module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, async.js

Im trying to call a function exported from another file inside a **async each** loop in which it iterates over an array of incoming data and executes queries accordingly like this :

```
const query = require('./queries')
    function receive(req,resp ,doneFunc){
        const listData = [];
        let checkedList = req.body.checkedList
        async.each(checkedList, (item, next)=>{
           //Every iteration gets a parameter called action from an object inside the array which is the 
            //name of the function needed
            //
          query[item.action](req, res, resp, (err, data)=>{

            listData.push(data);
            if(listData.length === checkedList.length)doneFunc(listData);
            next();
          });
        }, err=>{
           console.log(err);
        });
      }
```

The function im calling in `query[item.action]` has the following structure

```
exports.any = function(res,callback){
    MongoClient.connect(url,function (err, client) {
        let dbo = client.db("DB")
        if(!err) {
            dbo.collection("collection",function(err ,coll){

                coll.aggregate([
                    //make aggregation
                ]).toArray(function(err,data){
                   //execute callback when the aggregation has finished , this is where the error ocurrs
                    if(!err) return callback(null,data)
                    return callback(err,null)
                })

            })
        } else {
            return callback(err,null);
        }
    });


}
```

When the execution of the **async.each** loop reaches the call for **query** it returns the message

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at ...\server\routes\queries.js:385:37
```

Which is where the **return callback(null,data)** is supposed to be executed. 
What is the reason of this error , is the function set wrong or is it executed in a wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question (despite a lot of code missing to understand the question), this is the mistake:

```
function(res,callback){                             // function signature

query[item.action](req, res, resp, (err, data)=>{   // function call
```

They do not match at all, you are passing `res` as `callback` and inside function you are using `callback` (which actually is `res`) as a function.

Comment: How is it possible that callback is not being recognized?

Comment: also the error is reported on the queries file not on the execution file

Comment: If i have understood your code this should be a function argument exception in the Node.js VM. Can you improve your question to explain how and where are this functions called? mainly the `query[item.action]` is not exactly clear